# Any reason to use a Git alias instead of a git-* script?

Tags: git, alias

In Git, you can create custom commands using either an alias or by creating an executable file, included in your PATH, starting with `git-`. Is there any reason to choose an alias as opposed to a script?

I work with a team of developers and have made some handy aliases I'd like to share with them. A colleague of mine suggested that aliases should be used for simple things, like shortening a command (e.g. `git co` as an alias for `git checkout`), and that scripts would be useful for more complicated tasks, like combining multiple functions into one. But he couldn't come up with any reason why not to use scripts, not sure if it's just how he felt it should be, or if he had heard somewhere that that's how it should be, or what.

Our team all works on the same development server, so if I can use a script, I can simply put it in `/usr/local/bin` and everyone will have access to it automatically. So even with a simple alias, it would be much more convenient to just have it as a git script so that everyone automatically has it, as opposed to me having to tell everyone to set it up individually. Not to mention, when a new developer starts, we would have to remember to have them set it up as well.

I know it sounds like I'm campaigning for the script approach, and I am. I'm just wondering if there is any drawback to using that approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases are defined via git's config mechanism, so they can apply to either the whole system, a single user, or just a single repository, depending on whether you define them in `/etc/gitconfig`, `~/.gitconfig` or `$GIT_DIR/config`.  If you copy your own .gitconfig to a new machine, it will include all your personal aliases by copying a single file, which seems less overhead than copying a full directory and setting up `PATH` correctly to find your files.

Comment: Had no idea about the system-wide git config. I think it sounds like the best idea to use the system git config for shortening regular git commands, and the shell scripts for the heavy-lifting combined commands. The question was not really about ease of migrating the commands to a new machine, but setting up a new user on the same server, so as long as we can set the aliases up to apply to all users on the system (which we can, as you've pointed out), that works for us. Thank you!

Comment: Note that a script may be called from within an alias definition. In that case, sharing your Git config file(s) with others won't be enough; you'll also need to share the script in question.

Answer (score 4):

With using git aliases you will be able to use autocompletion of branch names, tags, etc

Comment: +1 Very valid point. Just tried it and sure enough, autocomplete works with an alias, but not with a script. Thank you!

Comment: auto-completion will work if you name the script like `git-foo`